# In tastypie-swagger, what should be the value for 'TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE' in setting file?

Tags: django, tastypie

In `tastypie-swagger`,  what should be the value for `TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE` in setting file?

Answer (score 2):

From [django-tastypie-swagger](https://github.com/minism/django-tastypie-swagger):

Define `TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE` in your settings. It should be a python path to your instance of [tastypie.api.Api](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html):

```
TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE = 'mainsite.urls.api'
```

Comment: Do we need to add any specific things to models to list them as resources? As I added above things and got Swigger UI to start working but I am not able to list any of my apis

Comment: Can you add your code for where your api is defined? (ie `api = Api(api_name='v1')`)

Comment: I tried lot of things but I still get 500 : INTERNAL SERVER ERROR /api/doc/resources/?api_key=special-key on Swagger UI

Comment: I was able to solve it yesterday. The tweak lied in **TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE**

Comment: What do you mean the tweak lied? What tweak?

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE. My api is defined at 'my_app.urls.api_v1'. my_app.urls is not in sys.modules - not sure that it should be. What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: It needs to be the path to your tastypie api instance. So, if there is a line `api_v1 = Api(api_name='v1')` in `my_app/urls.py`, then the setting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had named my api instance something slightly different.

In `ProjectName/urls.py` I have:

```
...
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
...
```

which means that I needed to put this in `settings.py`:

```
TASTYPIE_SWAGGER_API_MODULE = 'ProjectName.urls.v1_api'
```